# JSF a4j:support Rerender on UI doesn't work

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, ajax4jsf

**I am working on JSF a4j componenet.**

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="sampleSelect" value="#{myBackingBean.id}"
    immediate="true">
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBackingBean.generateSampleList}"/>
    <h:outputLabel value="Sample List : " for="sampleSelect"></h:outputLabel>
    <a4j:support ajaxSingle="true" 
                 event="onchange" 
                 reRender="dataTable1, dataTable2, dataTable3"
                 oncomplete="setColorbox();" 
                 action = "#{myBackingBean.setSampleListForDatatables}">
    </a4j:support>  
    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

And my **datatable** as

```
<h:panelGroup id="dataTable1">
    <h:dataTable value="#{myBackingBean.anotherBean.sampleList}" 
                 var="sampleList"
                 styleClass="table">
        <h:column>
            ....
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
    </h:panelGroup>
```

I have **multiple datatables** like same which are **changed on this ajax call** and should be reRendered on complete of ajax call.

At server side data is changed perfectly but not modified on UI.

For checking purpose What I did is.... Used,

```
<h:column>
    <%=new java.util.Date()%>
</h:column>
```

in datatables that is not modified after my ajax call.

Can any one suggest any thing to me?

From some post I come to know I have to use immediate="true" that I already done. But no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer

```
<h:dataTable value="#{myBackingBean.anotherBean.sampleList}" 
             var="sampleList"
             styleClass="table" 
             id="dataTable1">
    <h:column>
        ....
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

I removed `h:panelGroup` and put that id to `h:datatable` and that works. :)